# Beginner - pointer reassignment error Member access within Null Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, null-pointer

Struggling to understand why newLL is remaining as a null pointer in the following code (*Line 30: Char 16: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode' (solution.cpp)*) while temp0 is behaving as expected. Thank you for the help.

Problem: 
You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list. You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

```
/**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
* struct ListNode {
*     int val;
*     ListNode *next;
*     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
* };
*/
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {

    ListNode *temp0 = NULL;
    ListNode *temp1 = l1;
    ListNode *temp2 = l2;

    //keep track of head
    ListNode *newLL = temp0;

    int x, y, z, f;

    //sum val's and create new nodes on newLL, until l1 or l2 hits a null
    while(temp1 != NULL && temp2 != NULL){
        x = temp1->val;
        y = temp2->val;
        z = x + y;

        temp0 = new ListNode(z);
        cout << temp0->val << endl;  //no error
        cout << newLL->val << endl;  //error

        temp0 = temp0->next;

        temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;

        //concatenate the rest of l1 or l2 onto newLL
        if (temp1 == NULL){
            while (temp2 != NULL){
                y = temp2->val;

                temp0 = new ListNode(y);
                temp0 = temp0->next;

                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
        }
        if (temp2 == NULL){
            while (temp1 != NULL){
                x = temp1->val;

                temp0 = new ListNode(x);
                temp0 = temp0->next;

                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
        }
    }

    //loop through and for all numbers > 9, carry the digit
    temp0 = newLL;
    int r,d;

    while (temp0 != NULL) {
        if (temp0->val > 9){
            d = temp0->val / 10;
            r = temp0->val % 10;
            temp0->val = d;
            temp0 = temp0->next;
            temp0->val += r;
        } else {
            temp0 = temp0->next;
        }
    }
    //return newLL
    return newLL;
    }
};
```

Comment: The program looks to me a little bit too complicated. I think you do not need the temp pointers. ("temp" is most ofen a bad name for objects.)
What means "in reversed order"? - I would interpret it like "reversed related to the sense of how humans read numbers". So, the first node in the list contains the one's digit, then the ten's digit. Right? 
If so, you need only a carry variable and parse both lists in parallel. If one list is longer, go on creating the new list elements for the sum until the carry is 0.

Comment: There's exactly one place where `newLL` is given a value: `ListNode *newLL = temp0;` At that point, `temp0` is `NULL`, so `newLL` also gets the value of `NULL`. It's never given any other value, so of course it remains `NULL`. You seem to believe that `ListNode *newLL = temp0;` somehow glues the two variables together, so when one changes, the other does too; that's not how things work at all.

Comment: As @IgorTandetnik said - what you are probably expecting is the results from a pointer to a pointer which newLL is not - try `ListNode **newLL = &temp0;`

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Appreciate you all taking the time.